# How to apply a url path in after pseudo element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following css

```
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3 {
    background: url(../images/icon-news.jpg)no-repeat center left;
    position: relative;
}
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3:after{
    background: url(../images/icon-all-news.jpg) no-repeat right center;
    content: url(www.google.com);
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 9px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
}
```

How can I make `h3:after background` **clickable**?

---

Please note I can't wrap the `h3 tag` with `a tag`

---

If its not possible, how can I assign this a href using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with CSS, a jQuery solution would look something like this:

```
var $link = $('<a>',{
    class: 'all-news-link',
    href: 'http://google.com'
});

$('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').append($link);
```

Then you'd change your CSS to:

```
#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3 .all-news-link{
    background: url(../images/icon-all-news.jpg) no-repeat right center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 9px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the result? is the element being added? what happens when you click?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar how does it look then? can you right-click it and select the "Inspect element" option and see if everything looks ok there?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar are you sure there's an element in your page that matches the selector `#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3`? can you post your HTML markup, preferably in a fiddle? also try adding display:inline-block to the CSS

Comment: yes, you can build html nodes that way, try adding this to the code to see if we're matching any elements `alert($('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').length);` also are you placing the code inside your `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar, it is being appended and wrapped but the fiddle doesn't have the styles so you don't see it, check this one http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/66KaJ/2/

Comment: @NavinRauniyar wait a minute, do you want to wrap the whole `<h3>` in a link? I just created a new element to reproduce what you were trying to do with the :after in CSS

Comment: Oh! It was my big mistake I din't place css for that. Should I remove :after ?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar yes the :after in the CSS is not needed anymore