# how to assign php link to jquery?

Tags: jquery, joomla

To achieve my goal as of this question [How to apply a url path in after pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681364/how-to-apply-a-url-path-in-after-pseudo-element) I want to assign a link to the menu item id.

Within php code I wrote this:

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItem(474);
?>
```

and the jquery code is as you see is :

```
var $link = $('<a>',{
    class: 'all-news-link',
    href: <?php $item; ?> // **here how to assign the link which is assigned in php?**
});

$('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').append($link);
```

---

**update**

As per the provided link I used json_encode but also not solved my problem. Its even not alerting now.

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$link1 = $menu->getItem(474);
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
var $link = $('<a>',{
    class: 'all-news-link',
    href: <?php echo json_encode( $link1 ); ?>
});
$('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').append($link);
alert("hi"); // it is not alerting
});

</script>
```

> when href: 'http://www.google.com/' used its alerting "hi" but when I use php json_encode() its even not alerting means jquery is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link should be a string.

```
$item = $menu->getItem(474);
```

returns a `stdClass`.

You should get the route:

```
$id = 474;
$link = JRoute::_($menu->getItem($id)->link);
```

Try this:

```
$(function(){  
    var $link = $('<a>',{
        class: 'all-news-link',
        href: <?php echo json_encode( $link ); ?>
    });
    $('#custom-module .moduletable:nth-child(2) h3').append($link);
});
```

This sets `href` to be a valid Javascript string.

Comment: it will not show the background now.

Comment: Please post the output of this section.

Comment: It's saying parse error.

Comment: Do you actually have a menu item with that id? please post the output of `var_dump($menu->getItem(474));`.

Comment: Yes I've the menu with that id.

Comment: I accidentally wrote `$JRoute` where it should've been `JRoute`. If you have a menu with this id it should be fine now.

Comment: Yeah you are right. 1 more question >> How could I assign option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=474 to the link I want to link to module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37010/discussion-between-masteram-and-navin-rauniyar)

Comment: I was surprising when mouseover there is 468 no 474 so I supposed to place option=..... any idea?